# Emergence of symmetry in phase transition

Tags: symmetry, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking

Goldenfeld's book on phase transitions contains the following claim (in the context if discussing the Landau symmetry principle): **"Although a symmetry is either present or absent, it can *emerge* either continuously or discontinuously *as the coupling constants are changed*.**

Could somebody clarify this statement? It seems contradictory, and there is no discussion in the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He is simply saying that the order parameter can be either continuous or discontinuous at the transition (continuous *vs* first-order phase transition).

As a simple example, consider the two-dimensional nearest-neighbor Potts model with $q$ colors: for each $i\in\mathbb{Z}^2$, $\sigma_i\in\{1,\dots,q\}$ and the Hamiltonian is $H=-\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle} \delta_{\sigma_i,\sigma_j}$.

This model undergoes a phase transition at a finite temperature $T_c(q)$:

- When $T>T_c(q)$, there is a unique Gibbs state, invariant under permutation of the colors. In particular, the fraction of vertices of each of the $q$ colors are equal.

$\hskip2in$[image: Typical configuration of the q=4 Potts model above T_c]

- When $T<T_c(q)$, there are $q$ distinct (extremal) Gibbs states $\mu^1,\dots,\mu^q$. In the state $\mu^k$, the fraction of vertices of color $k$ is strictly larger than the fraction of vertices of any of the other $q-1$ colors: the symmetry under permutation of the $q$ colors is broken.

$\hskip2in$[image: Typical configuration of the q=4 Potts model below T_c]

So, when $T>T_c(q)$, the symmetry under permutation of the $q$ colors is present. When $T<T_c(q)$, it is absent. However, the way things occur *at $T_c(q)$* depends dramatically on the number of colors. To quantify that, it is useful to introduce a quantity to detect the presence/absence of the symmetry, that is, an order parameter. An natural choice is
$$
m = \sum_{k=1}^q e^{2ik\pi/q} \rho_k
$$
where $\rho_k$ is the density of vertices with color $k$. In terms of $m$, the behavior discussed above can be rephrased as:

- $m(T,q) = 0$ for all $T>T_c(q)$
- $m(T,q) \neq 0$ for all $T<T_c(q)$

The behavior at $T_c(q)$ can then be shown to be the following:

- When $q\geq 5$, at $T_c(q)$ there are $q+1$ (extremal) Gibbs states: the $q$ ordered low-temperature states coexist with the disordered high-temperature state. The order parameter $m$ is discontinuous at $T_c(q)$: the transition is of first order.
- When $2\leq q\leq 4$, there is a unique, disordered, Gibbs state at $T_c(q)$. This state is still symmetric under permutation of the colors. The order parameter $m$ is still equal to $0$ at $T_c(q)$ and depends continuously on $T$: the transition is continuous. As $T$ increases toward $T_c(q)$, the difference between the $q$ phases becomes smaller and smaller and the $q$ phases become indistinguishable at $T_c(q)$.

So, in the first case, the symmetry appears discontinuously, while in the second case it "appears continuously" (in the sense explained above).

Comment: I could not find pictures (simulations) showing the two possible behaviors of the order parameter at the transition. If somebody knows where to find some, he can add them.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the details on the Potts model. So, if one decomposes the state below $T_c$ into a mixture of the  symmetric background and the lower symmetry component, it is their proportion that changes continuously, while the symmetry is broken abruptly once $T<T_c$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The density of the dominant color goes continuously down to $1/q$ as $T$ increases toward $T_c$. This is for $2\leq q\leq 4$. For larger values of $q$, the density of the dominant color remains strictly larger than $1/q$ up to $T_c$ and then jumps discontinuously to $1/q$.

Comment: @Yvan Velenik   Sir, will you please check my questions
 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544620/in-renormalization-group-theory-why-fixed-point-gives-self-similar-probability

Answer (score 1):

He probably means that order parameter may or may not present a discontinuity.

For example, in the Ising model for the paramagnetic to ferromagnetic phase transition, the order parameter is the magnetisation $M$. I will consider spins that can either be up or down, no 3D orientation. When $M=\pm1$, all the spins are aligned in the same together, so there is a definite symmetry with respect to the fully random case $M=0$.

As you decrease the temperature $T$ to and below the Curie temperature $T_c$, the curve depends on the value of the external magnetic field $H$.

In the complete absence of a field $H = 0$, then the magnetisation curve picks up from $0$ to a finite value *discontinuously* only at $T=T_c$. 
 But if there is a background $H\neq 0$, this can "help" the symmetry manifestation start sooner, so you have a continuous function. 
 At $T=0$ and at $T\rightarrow \infty$, however, the two curves agree: so they agree on the symmetry being present or absent.

Depending on how rigourous your definition of "phase transition" is, only the $H=0$ case would qualify as such, because it displays a discontinuity.

[image]

Comment: What you say about $H=0$ vs $H\neq 0$ makes sense. You probably made a typo writing *1D Ising model*, since in 1D there is no phase transition at finite temperature.

Comment: Ah sorry. What I meant is for spins that can only be aligned up or down. I will edit.

Comment: Many things are worded in a wrong way in this answer. First, there is no discontinuity at the transition, at least in the sense it is traditionally used (the magnetization remains continuous at the transition). Second, you say that "there is a definite symmetry" when $M=\pm 1$, while it is absent when $M=0$. That's wrong, again at least in the usual sense of these words: the symmetry in this model refers to invariance under spin flip and is thus present (at $H=0$) when $T\geq T_c$ but absent (broken) when $T<T_c$.

Comment: Finally, I don't think that what he meant is the different behavior when $H=0$ vs $H\neq 0$. There is no symmetry when $H\neq 0$ and nothing "emerges" there. I think that he referred to the fact that the order parameter can be either continuous at the phase transition (e.g., Ising) or discontinuous (e.g., Potts for large enough number of states).

Comment: Yes, I just had a look at the book, he clearly discusses first-order vs continuous phase transitions here.