# In renormalization group theory, why fixed point gives self-similar probability distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, renormalization

I got this question when learning Kardar’s course “Statistical Physics of Fields”. The description of this question can be found in [Chapter 4 of Kardar's book.](http://www.physics.utah.edu/~starykh/phys7640/Lectures/Kardar-Chap4.pdf)  In his lectures, the renormalization group transformation is described by

$${m^\prime }\left( {{{\bf{x}}^\prime }} \right) = \frac{1}{{\zeta {b^d}}}\int_{{\rm{Cell of size }}b{\rm{ centered at }}b{x^\prime }} {{d^d}} {\bf{x}}m({\bf{x}})$$

here $m(x)$ is original field of the order parameter(suppose we are dealing with a d-dimensional Ising spin model) and ${m^\prime }\left( {{{\bf{x}}^\prime }} \right)$ is the one after RG transformation. $\varsigma$ is the contrast factor.

The probability of the statistical field is 
$${\cal P}[m({\bf{x}})] \propto \exp ( - \beta {\cal H}[m({\bf{x}})])$$
where the effective Hamiltonian is 
$$\beta {\cal H} = \int {{{\rm{d}}^d}} {\bf{x}}\left[ {\frac{t}{2}{m^2} + u{m^4} + v{m^6} +  \cdots  + \frac{K}{2}{{(\nabla m)}^2} + \frac{L}{2}{{\left( {{\nabla ^2}m} \right)}^2} +  \cdots } \right]$$

Then he introduced an infinite dimensional parameter space $S \equiv (t,u,v, \cdots ,K,L, \cdots )$.

The RG transfomation produces a new field with 
$${\cal P}[{m^\prime }\left( {{{\bf{x}}^\prime }} \right)] \propto \exp ( - \beta {\cal H}[{m^\prime }\left( {{{\bf{x}}^\prime }} \right)])$$
and the effective Hamiltonian 
$$\beta {{\cal H}^\prime }\left[ {{m^\prime }\left( {{{\bf{x}}^\prime }} \right)} \right] = \ln {{\cal P}^\prime }\left[ {{m^\prime }\left( {{{\bf{x}}^\prime }} \right)} \right] = {f_b} + \int {{{\rm{d}}^d}} {{\bf{x}}^\prime }\left[ {\frac{{{t^\prime }}}{2}{m^{\prime 2}} + {u^\prime }{m^{\prime 4}}} \right.\left. { + v{m^{\prime 6}} +  \cdots  + \frac{{{K^\prime }}}{2}{{\left( {\nabla {m^\prime }} \right)}^2} + \frac{{{L^\prime }}}{2}{{\left( {{\nabla ^2}{m^\prime }} \right)}^2} +  \cdots } \right]$$
with the RG transformation (denoted as ${\Re _b}$) in the parameter space ${S^\prime } = {\Re _b}S$.

Then he said that at the critical point, the self-similar probability or Hamiltonian must corresponds to the fixed point in the parameter space ${\Re _b}{S^*} = {S^*}$.

I got a puzzle here, I can understand that the probability should be similar between ${\cal P}[m({\bf{x}})]$ and ${\cal P}[{m^\prime }\left( {{{\bf{x}}^\prime }} \right)]$. But do we have

$$\int {{{\rm{d}}^d}} {\bf{x}}\left[ {\frac{{{t^*}}}{2}{m^2} + {u^*}{m^4} + {v^*}{m^6} +  \cdots  + \frac{{{K^*}}}{2}{{(\nabla m)}^2} + \frac{{{L^*}}}{2}{{\left( {{\nabla ^2}m} \right)}^2} +  \cdots } \right] = {f_b} + \int {{{\rm{d}}^d}} {{\bf{x}}^\prime }\left[ {\frac{{{t^*}}}{2}{m^{\prime 2}} + {u^*}{m^{\prime 4}}} \right.\left. { + {v^*}{m^{\prime 6}} +  \cdots  + \frac{{{K^*}}}{2}{{\left( {\nabla {m^\prime }} \right)}^2} + \frac{{{L^*}}}{2}{{\left( {{\nabla ^2}{m^\prime }} \right)}^2} +  \cdots } \right]$$

In my opinion, the above equation relies on the choice of this ${f_b}$ term. Then why sould we emphasize that only at the fixed point can we got the self-similar probability? It can be achieved for any ${S^\prime } = {\Re _b}S$ if we carefully choose the ${f_b}$ term. Thank your for your patience for my long question.

**Added on 20200421**

I mean if we are not at the fixed point, after RG transformation, why can't we have unchanged probability distribution or Hamiltonian. That is, 
$${m_1}({\bf{x}})\mathop  \to \limits^{RG} {m_2}({\bf{x'}})$$
$${S_1}\mathop  \to \limits^{RG} {S_2}$$
with
$${S_1} \equiv ({t_1},{u_1},{v_1}, \cdots ,{K_1},{L_1}, \cdots )$$
$${S_2} \equiv ({t_2},{u_2},{v_2}, \cdots ,{K_2},{L_2}, \cdots )$$
and ${S_1} \ne {S_2}$

Then why can't we have 
$$\int {{{\rm{d}}^d}} {\bf{x}}\left[ {\frac{{{t_1}}}{2}{m_1}^2 + {u_1}{m_1}^4 + {v_1}{m_1}^6 +  \cdots  + \frac{{{K_1}}}{2}{{(\nabla {m_1})}^2} + \frac{{{L_1}}}{2}{{\left( {{\nabla ^2}{m_1}} \right)}^2} +  \cdots } \right] = {f_b} + \int {{{\rm{d}}^d}} {{\bf{x}}^\prime }\left[ {\frac{{{t_2}}}{2}{m_2}^2 + {u_2}{m_2}^4 + {v_2}{m_2}^6 +  \cdots  + \frac{{{K_2}}}{2}{{(\nabla {m_2})}^2} + \frac{{{L_2}}}{2}{{\left( {{\nabla ^2}{m_2}} \right)}^2} +  \cdots } \right]  
   (*)$$
such that $P({m_1}({\bf{x}})) = P({m_2}({\bf{x'}}))$

Comment: He is talking about the probability distribution. Note that the $f_b$ term is independent of the value of the field and thus disappears when you compute probabilities (it appears both in the numerator (Boltzmann weight) and the denominator (partition function)).

Comment: @YvanVelenik Thank you for your kind reply! I have added some statement at the end to make my question more clear. My question is why only at the fixed point can the probability distribution or Hamiltonian stay unchanged after RG transformation.

Comment: @FaDA: To answer "why only at the fixed point ... unchanged after RG transformation", I think that's the definition of the fixed point.

Comment: @Sidd Thanks for your kind reply! But in my opinion, the definition of the fixed point ${S^*}$ is  ${\Re _b}{S^*} = {S^*}$ where ${\Re _b}$ is the RG transforamtion

Comment: Well, you certainly can have, in principle, $P(m_1(x)) = P(m_2(x'))$ at specific values $m_1$ and $m_2$ of the field. But the functional $\beta\mathcal{H}$ is assumed to be completely characterized by the coefficients encoded in $S$, so that the renormalized probability measure will coincide with the original (that is coincide at *all* $m$) only if $S$ is left invariant, which is the definition of the fixed points, as @Sidd said.

Comment: Note also that real-space renormalization group as described here is in general ill-defined. There is a [well-known paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9210032) about that. The proper way to define such transformations is at the level of the probability measures and not the Hamiltonians (or coupling constants). Since the Gibbs property is often lost, it is not possible to go from the flow on measures to a flow on Hamiltonians, because the latter become ill defined.

Comment: Finally, let me say that I am not a specialist of this type of problem. One user who is  a specialist and might answer you better is @AbdelmalekAbdesselam .

Comment: @YvanVelenik Thank you for your patience！ I will try to go through the reference you provided.